# Why do some of our Kafka Consumer Groups have no offsets listed even though they are associated with topics?

Tags: apache-kafka

Folks, I'm wondering if someone can help me. I'm trying to understand offsets work w.r.t. consumer groups in Kafka. We're using the [kaf](https://github.com/birdayz/kaf) tool to get metadata about some consumer groups, and we have two:

```
$kaf group describe connect-something-platform-db2-sink-VW_ORDERS_2
Group ID:        connect-something-platform-db2-sink-VW_ORDERS_2
State:           Stable
Protocol:        range
Protocol Type:   consumer
Offsets:
  kc_something-db2-source-VW_ORDERS:
    Partition  Group Offset  High Watermark  Lag  Metadata
    ---------  ------------  --------------  ---  --------
    0          57            58              1
Members:
  connector-consumer-something-platform-db2-sink-VW_ORDERS_2-0:
    Host:  /169.254.0.3
    Assignments:
      Topic                         Partitions
      -----                         ----------
      kc_something-db2-source-VW_ORDERS  [0]%
```

```
$ kaf group describe connect-something-campaign-db2-sink-VW_PEOPLE_2
Group ID:       connect-something-campaign-db2-sink-VW_PEOPLE_2
State:          Stable
Protocol:       range
Protocol Type:  consumer
Offsets:
Members:
 connector-consumer-something-campaign-db2-sink-VW_PEOPLE_2-0:
   Host: /169.254.0.3
   Assignments:
     Topic                         Partitions
     -----                         ----------
     kc_something-db2-source-VW_PEOPLE [0]%
```

What we're trying to understand is why, in the second case, there would be no offsets listed. As can be seen, the consumer group is associated with a topic and a partition, so I would have expected to see some offsets shown, even if those offsets are 0.

Is this a valid state? If so, what does it mean?

Comment: If the consumer group is not *comitting* offsets, nothing will be shown apart from the topics and partitions the consumer group is subscribed to. Or, the consumer group has not yet started to consume anything at all.

Comment: @mike I guess I missed out part of the story also... these consumer groups will ultimately be coming from Kafka Connect (in both cases). So I guess I find it surprising that offsets are committed in one case and not the other.